# Java form validation

Tags: java, spring

I have a website which has a search box. I want to validate the search box when a user clicks on *search* without entering any text. He should get an error message, but I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'searchForm' available as request attribute

My form is as follows:

```
<blc:form th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${searchForm}"  method="POST">
    <input type="search" class="search" name="q" th:value="${originalQuery}" />
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('searchText')}" th:errors="*{searchText}">dddd</span>
    <input type="submit" id="search_button" value="go" />
</blc:form>
```

My controller is as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchController extends Mysearchcontroller {
    @RequestMapping("")
    public String search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String q,@ModelAttribute("mysearchForm") Mysearchform mysearchForm,BindingResult errors,Model model) throws ServletException, IOException, ServiceException {
        return search3(model, request,response, q ,errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `blc` namespace?

Comment: I don't think you can mix thymeleaf and JSP tag libs if that is what you are doing.

Comment: For other forms validation they are using same structure.I am using braodleaf

Comment: Where is `fields` coming from? It doesn't seem to be a model or request attribute.

Comment: Fields are coming from validator class of spring my custom validatorlook                                                         public class Mysearchvalidator implements Validator {
 
 
 public static void validate(String query, Errors errors) {
  if (query == null || query.length() == 0 ||query.contains("Please Enter your Text")) {
   
   errors.reject("q", "searchText.required");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "searchText", "searchText.required");
        }
  
    }

Answer (score -2):

You can use the spring validators 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: I'd like to know why my response was downvoted. If it's wrong would be great to learn about it...

Comment: I should have explained myself. This answer states a method of providing model attribute validation. OP hasn't reached that point yet. The error they are describing is a missing model attribute. This answer won't help them solve that.